# Приставка НЕ, словообразование

Tags: приставка

> Только раздельно пишутся слова, которые не используют приставку НЕ для
> образования нового слова (не красный, не лесной, не узкий).

Почему эти слова не используют приставку НЕ? Чем они отличаются от других?
Нужно объяснить пример

> Дом **невысокий**. Но дом **не узкий**.

Comment: Интересный вопрос (мой голос).  В правилах обычно утверждается этот факт, но не объясняется. Вероятно, надо думать, что это само собой ясно. Ясно многим, но не всем. Мне  вот не было ясно...

Comment: Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник. — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998. 
Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В.  
Эти словари рекомендуют слитное написание слова "нелесной".

Comment: @guaranteen
Орфографический словарь на Грамоте.ру: нелесной* Не подскажите, что означает звездочка. Это дополнительная информация, а какая? https://orfo.ruslang.ru/search/word

Comment: Русский язык. Школьный курс. В помощь ученикам: НЕ… «Приставка, придающая слову <...> 2) значение противопоставления (слову без «не»), отрицания, отсутствия (того, что заключено в значении слова без «не»), напр. **некрасный**, несемейный, нечитанный, неиграющий, несоциалист, невручение, неприглашение и т. п.

Comment: А ссылка на этот удивительный учебник есть? Некрасный – это какой? В словаре РАН этого слова  нет.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что частотность. Когда ‟не” начинает употребляеться с качественным прилагательным в утверждениях без противоречия некому утверждению в контексте, которое высказывается напрямую или подразумевается, то часто не совсем ясно, отрицается ли здесь наличие характеристики или утверждается противоположная. И если ‟не” с какими-то словами употреблялось очень часто, то в восприятии побеждал вариант с утверждением противоположной характеристики. Эту проблему можно было решить при формировании языка, введя приставку (отличную от ‟не”) или приставки, которые бы обозначали противоположную характеристику, тогда бы люди знали, что когда ‟не”, то отрицается характеристика, а когда другая приставка или приставки, то утверждается противоположная характеристика.