# Может ли слово «некрасный» писаться слитно?

Tags: орфография, лексика, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Как известно, слово с приставкой НЕ можно найти **в словаре** (толковом и орфографическом).  Кроме того, такое слово должно обозначать **конкретный признак,** а не просто отрицать его.

А если *некрасный* (или, к примеру, *нелесной*) – то это **какой именно**?

В словаре РАН нет слова «некрасный», а вот «нелесной» есть (правда, со звездочкой).

Но вот в комментариях по одной из тем написано, что слова «некрасный» и «нелесной» есть [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474293/Приставка-НЕ-словообразование#comment507075_474293](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474293/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9D%D0%95-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#comment507075_474293)

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

*Я, конечно, не синий чулок. Но и не **красный** галстук. Охра не **красный** цвет. В ее комнате в глубине дворца прохлада и полумрак, и даже огонь в очаге не **красный**, как везде, а какой-то голубоватый*.

И только один пример, да и то по очень конкретной теме:

Возмущала и традиция отмечать еще один, **некрасный** день календаря ― 1 апреля.  Г. В. Андреевский. Повседневная жизнь Москвы в сталинскую эпоху. 1920-1930-е годы (2008)

Comment: Тут играет роль схема предложения и положение этого слова в схеме. Большинство людей пишут слитно всегда, когда слово с ‟не” входит в ряд однородных определений. Все те примеры с раздельным написанием являются сказуемыми или являются определениями у сказуемого, а слитное написание у слова в ряде однородных, и у дополнения.

Comment: Мне бы хотелось услышать, можно ли в принципе писать эти слова слитно и на какие источники надо  при этом сослаться (словари, учебники).

Comment: Скорее речь идет о другом значении слова - красивый.  Словарь русского языка XVIII века. — Л.: Наука, 1984, предлагает именно это значение. НЕКРАСИ́ВЫЙ (также раздельно) и ◨ НЕКРАСНЫЙ, ая, ое. Не отличающийся красотой, неприглядный. Не красив, не складен тѣлом, не статен собою. ВЛ 701. Оныя богини поют по перемѣнам нѣсколько арий о разных дѣйствиях краснаго и некраснаго человѣка. Прим. Вед. 1738 151.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, интересное замечание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два примера из корпуса.

*За последние годы в Подмосковье не было случая перевода лесных земель в нелесной фонд с последующей их застройкой...* Борис Устюгов. Щепки летят (2003)

*Семикилометровый поход от школы до своей деревни, обязательно ночью и непременно лесом (правда, в их деревню и не было нелесной дороги), затеяли вместе...* Алексей Иванов. За рекой, за речкой (1982)

И напрашивающаяся конструкция такого же типа, ссылки на которую нет.

*Не осталось ни одной некрасной линии.*

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий**

Спасибо за ответ!  Интересная получается ситуация…

В толковом словаре **этих слов нет**, то есть нет описания их утвердительного значения.

В орфографическом словаре РАН  есть только слово ***«нелесной»,***  но со звездочкой.

Есть термины  ***нелесной фонд, нелесные земли***, но это специальная лексика.

А вот «нелесные дороги» можно записать как «не (лесные дороги)»,  «некрасная линия» – как «не (красная линия)», то есть НЕ отнести к **словосочетанию**.

Интересен пример «***некрасный день календаря»***, но здесь дни могут быть только черными или красными, тогда ***некрасный*** – это черный.

Таким образом, **все вопросы остаются**. Слов «некрасный» и  «нелесной» в общеупотребительном значении нет, но есть «нелесной» как специальный термин.
А вот употребление этих слов  в словосочетаниях  вызывает сомнение...

Comment: 1. Есть, и нельзя сказать, что его нет, слово некрасный (некрасивый). Только подзабыто. 2. Пример «*некрасный день календаря*» — он тоже не про цвет, он про **невыходные** рабочие будни и **выходные**, связанные с облачением в красивое.

Comment: Да, а я думала, что это цвет  в календаре в прямом значении))    А здесь –негосударственный праздник. И что подзабыто, того в словаре уже нет...