# Папа купил не зелёную чечевицу / незелёную чечевицу

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Папа купил не зелёную чечевицу / незелёную чечевицу.`

`— Эта болезнь излечима?`

`— Нет, она не излечима / неизлечима.`

> Было две команды: зелёные и незелёные / не зелёные.

> Есть два сорта гречи: коричневая и некоричневая / не коричневая.``

> Я купил не серебряные / несеребряные часы.

> У меня было две пары часов, и я несеребряные / не серебряные носил.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что однотипный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Сегодня сварим суп из зеленой чечевицы. — Да, но папа купил **не зелёную чечевицу.*** Ему больше оранжевая понравилась.

*— Эта болезнь излечима? — Нет, она **неизлечима**.*

*Было две команды: зелёные и **не зелёные**. Желто-зеленые, кажется.*

*Есть два сорта гречи: коричневая и **не коричневая**. Цвет у нее кремовый, желтовато-зеленый.*

*Я купил **не серебряные** часы. Серебряные мне не понравились.*

*У меня было две пары часов, и я **не серебряные** (часы) носил.*

**Пояснение**

1. **[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)** Пункт 5. Частица не пишется раздельно и с качественными прилагательными, которые обозначают цвет и в сочетании с не слов с противоположным значением не образуют: краска не синяя; переплёт не жёлтый; оттенок не серый.
2. Если есть **утвердительная** форма ***неизлечимый***, то используется эта форма. Отрицание возможно при **противопоставлении**, а также в **усилительных** конструкциях.
3. Частица ***НЕ*** может относиться **к словосочетанию**: не серебряные часы, а другие часы.
4. Слитное написание ***НЕ*** с относительными прилагательными возможно, если образуется **новое понятие**: ***нездешняя** (= необычная) красота.*

**Пример:** *Решение о контрударе явно принимали **не зеленые лейтенанты**, так что, как ни верти, а приказ они явно получили...*

**НЕИЗЛЕЧИМЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -чим, -а, -о. Такой, который не излечивается. Н. больной. Н-ая болезнь. СПИД в настоящее время неизлечим.

Comment: Но и Розенталь, и Лопатин, и вы говорите, что можно писать как и *не хорош*, так и *нехорош*, что определяется смыслом.

Comment: Разве нельзя начать писать *несеребряные* потому, что это уже субстантивированное сущ.? Мы же, например, пишем *неметаллы*.

Comment: Если нет слов незеленый, несеребряный, то их нельзя использовать. // Субстантивации здесь нет, просто неполное словосочетание. Восстанавливается по контексту.  // Неметаллы – это конкретное понятие, их можно перечислить.

Comment: Вспомнились ваши рассуждения о "некрасном (= невыходном) дне календаря"... И где-то, не помню где, встречалось о слитном написании, если... не помню... Короче, команда, думаю, может называться "Незелёные".

Comment: Сомнительно... Контекст нужен. Команду можно назвать зелеными, но какой утвердительный смысл в незеленых?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Саша, вот он, этот "некрасный вопрос": *Может ли слово «некрасный» писаться слитно?* (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474325/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be) *То есть за 1 рубль мне продали 3 килограмма картошки, то есть стоит нынче указанная картошка 3,5 рубля ведро, небольшое, **незеленое**, не очень высокое, безо всякой там эмали...* (Евгений Попов. Во времена моей молодости).